# Como interpretar o conector de composição em um diagrama de classes?

Tags: classes, uml, diagrama, composição

O professor pediu para fazer um relacionamento entre pais, estado e cidade. Pelo o que eu entendi desse relacionamento eu fiz esse diagrama.

[image: Meu diagrama]

Só que ele falou que o lado do diamante está do lado errado e o certo seria desse jeito:

[image: Professor fez]

Só que eu ainda não entendi o motivo de ser desse lado. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Você tem que estar ciente do significado do diamante e a diferença dele estar de um lado ou do outro. Note que Um país possui muitos estados e um estado se localiza em um único país, um estado possui muitas cidades e uma cidade se localiza em um único estado.

Comment: pelo que eu entendi, o diamante fica do lado da classe todo. Um País contém vários Estados, então o diamante ficaria do lado da classe País.

Comment: @priscylam, o que determina o lado do diamante é o requisito, ele que vai mandar. Mas você deve ter em mente que o lado em que ela aparecer que vai referenciar o relacionamento. Se você mandar como estava escrito fica melhor de interpretar o problema. Na minha resposta mandei as duas interpretações possíveis e expliquei como cada uma delas é implementada.

Comment: @WilliamTeixeira sim, eu entendi pela sua explicação, obrigada, ajudou-me bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Composição

é um relação todo-parte forte. Indica que o todo é composto pelas partes. **A ponta da seta indica qual é o todo no relacionamento**. Na prática, a classe *todo* guarda a referência para a classe *parte*.

[Aqui na documentação fica mais claro o uso](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html)

[image: Exemplo 1]

Temos que uma pasta (Folder) é composta de arquivos (File).

## Problema

Provável que o seu professor tenha se confundido. É preciso muita atenção para interpretar corretamente os diagramas. Analisando os que você enviou:

- primeiro exemplo:

Um país é composto por estados que são compostos por cidades. Implementado como:

```
public class Pais {
    ...
    // um pais pode ter varios estados
    private ArryList<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

public class Estado {
    ...
    // um estado pode ter varias cidades
    private ArryList<Cidade> cidades = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}

public class Cidade {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Aqui queremos que para ser criado um País, obrigatoriamente deve existir no minimo um Estado o que implica na existência de pelo menos uma cidade.

- segundo exemplo:

Uma cidade é composta de no minimo um estado que é composto de no minimo um país. Implementado como:

```
public class Pais {
    ...
    ...
}

public class Estado {
    ...
    // um estado possui apenas um país
    private ArryList<Pais> paises = new ArrayList<>(1);
    ...
}

public class Cidade {
    ...
    // um cidade possui apenas um estado
    private ArryList<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<>(1);
    ...
}
```